# Connecting Device on IDE

Tags: android-studio, adb

Good day everyone, I am developing an android application in Android Studio. I want to connect my android phone and use it instead of an emulator(consume 1gb+ ram) and makes my PC so slow.

Now, the android studio can not detect my device ( I tried searching for troubleshooting but I am stuck). My phone is ASUS Zenfone GO Z00VD (ZC500TG) Lollipop version. Then I tried to connect another android phone (Jellybean version) and it is detecting.

Is it because my adb is outdated? Thank you for answers, suggestions, etc. in advance.

EDIT : Developer mode: Enabled , Debugging: Enabled
My phone Asus can be detected on another PC so I think the PC is the problem.

Comment: Are you able to install your device sucessfully? andable to open fils in my computer?

Comment: Did you enable the developer mode on your device?

Comment: @Nazimch yes I can open files

Comment: @HerrDerb Yes, as well as the Debugging option.

Comment: Edited post regarding dev option. Thankyou for response

Comment: please restart your pc and check again

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable developer mode on your device
http://blog.syncios.com/enable-developer-optionsusb-debugging-mode-on-devices-with-android-4-2-jelly-bean/